# Updated: Problem with executing SQL query from Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, netbeans

Updated:
so as per the suggestions i changed all the column name to strings and added prepared statements-

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/minor","root","alphabet")) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement stmt= conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM ? where name=? ;");
            PreparedStatement stmt2= conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM ? where name=? ;");
            stmt.setString(1, day_1);
            stmt.setString(2, faculty1);
            stmt2.setString(1,day_1);
            stmt2.setString(2, faculty2);
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            ResultSet rs1= stmt.executeQuery();
```

The day and faculty is retrieved from input screen, the queries work just fine in mysql workbench but the 'select' keyword goes missing when i try to run it from Java, see the following error-
[image: No select keyword]
The faculty1, faculty2 is retrieved from the following-
[image: retrieve]
The database looks like this-
[image: database]

Comment: Your query makes no sense, because you are trying to select from a string literal.  In addition, it is wide open for SQL injection.  Please review the basics of SQL before proceeding, and also read about prepared statements.

Comment: i changed the code and tried adding PreparedStatements.                 PreparedStatement stmt= conn.prepareStatement("select ? from ? ;"); stmt.setString(1,ts);                                                                              stmt.setString(2,day_1);                                                                          ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();            but now i get the error as stated- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''MONDAY'' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would recommend to use PreparedStatement instead of Statement, then at least you can bind your variables;
2. You query `select from time_interval from day_selected` is not correct, I don't think that it will execute anywhere, you need to have something between select and from, and not two from in one statement.

Comment: i changed the code and tried adding PreparedStatements.                   PreparedStatement  stmt= conn.prepareStatement("select ? from ? ;");
                stmt.setString(1,ts);
                stmt.setString(2,day_1);
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();                                                          but now i get the error as stated-  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''MONDAY'' at line 1

Comment: As I mentioned, your query is not valid, you can even see it in error log. Your query is:
`select8:30-9:00 from 'MONDAY'`
Do you think this is a valid query?

Comment: i got it, what you were saying. Please check the updated question. The issue still persists.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to bind table in prepared statement.